# Troubleshooting ping to active server

Tags: networking, dns, routing, ping

I have difficulty connecting to a specific server and need help on how to troubleshoot the problem.

First of all, I know the server is up and running and can respond to pings by using an online service like [centralops](https://centralops.net/co/Ping.aspx?addr=langhampreaching.org&count=5&timeout=1000&size=32&ttl=255&ip-version=auto)

I also have no difficulty pinging other domains from my laptop like

```
ping superuser.com
```

so I know I don't have to mess around with my firewall, router or network settings. I guess there must be some external routing issue with this specific domain. If I do a nslookup all looks fine:

```
> set type=soa
> langhampreaching.org.
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
langhampreaching.org
    origin = ns1.digitalocean.com
    mail addr = hostmaster.langhampreaching.org
    serial = 1502887081
    refresh = 10800
    retry = 3600
    expire = 604800
    minimum = 1800
```

If I do a traceroute, the route never completely resolves and I do not know how to interpret the results:

```
traceroute langhampreaching.org
traceroute to langhampreaching.org (146.185.173.86), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3)  1.035 ms  0.739 ms  0.606 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * 105-187-252-61.ti-sen.telkomsa.net (105.187.252.61)  25.076 ms  24.082 ms
 4  ipc-2-up.south.dsl.telkomsa.net (105.226.0.22)  25.209 ms  24.447 ms  23.873 ms
 5  ipc-aggr-2.south.dsl.telkomsa.net (105.226.0.57)  24.221 ms  106.377 ms  24.839 ms
 6  196.25.190.209 (196.25.190.209)  25.288 ms
    165.165.214.213 (165.165.214.213)  25.747 ms  24.812 ms
 7  196.43.9.106 (196.43.9.106)  187.357 ms  189.402 ms  187.685 ms
 8  * 212.119.15.65 (212.119.15.65)  187.306 ms  185.382 ms
 9  ae-5.r20.frnkge04.de.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.141)  189.973 ms  190.014 ms  191.320 ms
10  ae-9.r25.amstnl02.nl.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.3.77)  193.987 ms  196.832 ms  192.204 ms
11  ae-1.r03.amstnl02.nl.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.147)  200.547 ms
    ae-2.r02.amstnl02.nl.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.159)  199.837 ms  195.228 ms
12  83.231.213.94 (83.231.213.94)  193.606 ms  197.464 ms
    83.231.213.30 (83.231.213.30)  191.783 ms
13  * * *
14  * * *

...

64  * * *
```

I can see that the url is not short-circuited by my local hosts configuration or anything like that. How can one troubleshoot this further?

#### Update

DigitalOcean support folk has helpfully suggested [using the mtr tool](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-traceroute-and-mtr-to-diagnose-network-issues#how-to-use-mtr), but I am still unsure what to do when a traceroute fails between two ISP routers.

Comment: Are you certain this is a problem? I am able to traceroute without issue (18 hops with only 1 time out). The site seems otherwise available.

Comment: @Anuksunaman I guess this is exactly the problem. The site can be reached by my friends and by other websites like centralops, but not by me and i am trying to find out why.

Comment: Some hosts block the specific mechanisms traditional traceroute tools (such as tracert from the Windows command line) use. The particular path you're taking seems to have those hosts (apparently from NTT in @grawity's answer).

Comment: Thanks @Anak. Just to be clear, my primary problem is that I cannot visit this domain in my browser. The fact that ISPs along the way block packets originating from debugging tools like ping or traceroute should not affect a normal http request, right? Besides, their own looking glass service offers a traceroute that times out for me: http://kiekies.net/drop/link/ntt.png

Comment: No they shouldn't. Just as wild speculation, I wonder if there is some critical down along your path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be specifically with the connection between DigitalOcean's Amsterdam datacenter (the server's location) and NTT (one of the various ISPs along the way between you and the server).

Note that DigitalOcean can access the internet through multiple upstream ISPs, so different people will reach it through different paths, most of which still work fine. (For example, the server is still reachable through Telia, or through various direct peerings from other hosting companies.)

(While there are many mechanisms for instantly rerouting *broken* links, that doesn't always help with *misconfigured* ones, which can remain stuck until manually fixed...)

You can check it directly [from NTT](https://us.ntt.net/support/looking-glass/) and various other places by using "looking glass" websites. (Practically every large ISP will have one, just search for them.)

Comment: Very insightful! So my traceroute confirms that there is a router misconfiguration between NTT and DigitalOcean, right? I used NTT's looking glass service and the traceroute didn't resolve. Can I report the error somewhere? Is there anything I can do to restore the connection even temporarily / manually?

Comment: No, your primary option is to use a VPN.